# How to handle creation of db entries through celery async tasks in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions, celery

My system receives payload from another source. This payload contains items information, including brand and such.

I save this payload inside a buffer. Buffers are processed async with Celery tasks. Based on the payload we create the entries or update them if necessary. This is done by using an atomic transaction, in which we create the Item, the Brand and Category.

The issue I am running into is that it can be possible that two buffers both have an Brand which is not yet created in the db. Using update_or_create inside the atomic block I check whether it already exists. Since both buffers are ran async at almost exactly the same time both think the Brand does not yet exists. This means both of them try to create the Brand yielding me the following database error:

> postgres_1   | ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "catalogue_brand_name_key"
>   postgres_1   | DETAIL:  Key (name)=(Bic) already exists.
>   postgres_1   | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "catalogue_brand" ("id", "created_date", "modified_date", "name") VALUES ('c8e9f328-cee7-4b9b-ba45-268180c723d8'::uuid, '2018-12-28T08:08:51.519672+00:00'::timestamptz, '2018-12-28T08:08:51.519691+00:00'::timestamptz, 'Bic')

Since this is a db-level exception I am unable to catch it inside my code and the buffer will be marked as completed (since no exception inside the code was given).

The easy solution here is to not run the buffers async, but just one at a time.

Here is my part of the code:

```
@atomic
def create(self, data):

...


brand_obj = Brand.objects.update_or_create(
        name=brand['name'],
        defaults={
            'name': brand['name']
        }
     )[0]

...
```

Which is called through:

```
process_incoming.delay(buffer.pk)
```

Is it possible to run my buffers async without hitting db-level constraints?

Comment: (1) Why can't you catch the db-level exception? (2) how do you want the constraint violation resolved? (3) a dumb buffer - I'm assuming a fifo queue - isn't going to work if your work items have invariants between themselves that need to be observed (you'll need some sort of ordered or prioritized queue implementation that the workers can pick tasks off of).

Comment: The `atomic` decorator will suppress DB errors. Manage the transaction yourself in a try/except and you will be able to catch the error in your Python code.